# To run a function in another page

Tags: jquery

hello my english is not good , I hope you can understand me thank you

I got my 2 page , and I want to run the function on another page,
but  does not working In other pages function
thank you

example

A PAGE

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Apage.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        AFunction();
    });
</script>
```

A PAGE IN FUNCTION

```
function AFunction() {

    $("#test").load("BPage.aspx");
    BFunction();

}
```

B PAGE

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="pageb.BPage" %>


<script src="Bpage.js"></script>
 B PAGE LOADED..
```

B PAGE IN FUNCTION

```
function BFunction() {

        alert("Bfunction is working");


    }
```

test project
http://speedy.sh/yajS5/pagea.rar

http://i.hizliresim.com/w1LkLN.png

Answer (score 1):

Call function in `load` callback of `load()` so that the function is available for being called.

```
function AFunction() {
    $("#test").load("BPage.aspx", function(){
            BFunction();
    });
}
```

Comment: so why can not I use?... http://i.hizliresim.com/Kr3Vaz.png and I'am sory ,you can not score because I see this message
http://i.hizliresim.com/KP0oVv.png  thank you